# SimpleHTTPServer 404 message File not found (trying to load bootstrap.js)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, simplehttpserver

Can someone explain why I am getting the following error?

From the following directory, I am running "python -m SimpleHTTPServer"

```
[blah@blah:~/Dropbox/bootstrap]: ls
css     img     index.html  js
```

When I go to localhost:8000/ in my browser, I get the following error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2014 10:22:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2014 10:22:37] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2014 10:22:37] "GET /%E2%80%9Djs/bootstrap.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

And yes, in the js directory, I have the two files "bootstrap.js" and "bootstrap.min.js"

My index.html file looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My First Bootstrap Project</title>


    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1><a href="#">Bootstrap Site</a></h1>
        </div>


        <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”css/bootstrap.css”  type=”text/css”/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src=”js/bootstrap.js”></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may relate to the curly quotations (smart quotes) you're using in the HTML. Instead, use regular quotations:

```
regular: "
curly (smart): ”
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason I was getting a 404 error was because I already had a process running on port 8000; the solution was to free up the port first.

On Mac (Linux):

```
# If something is running on port 8000, this command will return
# the process with the process ID (PID) as the 2nd item
lsof -n -i :8000 | grep LISTEN

# Replace <PID> with whatever PID was returned above
kill -9 <PID>
```

After that I was able to run a new process on this port.